# vtk projection matrix: from world to display

Tags: graphics, 3d, vtk

I'm trying to obtain a 4x4 projection matrix that transforms a point in the world to the display coordinates.

Having a pixel (x, y) and the corresponding z-value (from the `zbuffer`), I obtain its 3D world coordinates with `vtkWorldPointPicker` class. Let's denote the result by **x**.

According to [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCamera.html#acb7e327cd7644e8ae885bac78221bc79), I can compute the view coordinates of the world point by applying the matrix `GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix` to **x**. Next, I'm using the transformation from the view to the initial display coordinates by using the code found in [`vtkViewport::ViewToDisplay`](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/52d45496877b00852a08a5b9819d109c2fd9bfab/Rendering/Core/vtkViewport.cxx#L219) (*):

```cpp
dx = (v[0] + 1.0) * (sizex*(v[2]-v[0])) / 2.0 + sizex*v[0];
dy = (v[1] + 1.0) * (sizey*(v[3]-v[1])) / 2.0 + sizey*v[1];
```

where `sizex` and `sizey` are the width and height of the image in pixels, and `v` are the computed view coordinates.

Unfortunately, the values I get back do not match the original:

```
display [0, 0, 0.716656] // x,y-pixel coordinates and the zbuffer
x = [0.0255492, -0.0392383, 0.00854707] // world coordinates  (using vtkWorldPointPicker)

// camera->GetCompositeProjectionTransformMatrix
P = [
 -1.84177         0         0         0
        0   1.20317   1.39445         0
        0  -757.134   653.275   -9.9991
        0 -0.757126  0.653268         0 ]

v = [-0.0470559, -0.0352919, 25.2931, 0.0352919] // P*x
a = [7697.18, -0.597848] // using (*)
```

Is this approach (in general) correct, or is there a more conventional way to do this? Thanks for any help.

**Edit:** the provided snippet from [`vtkViewport::ViewToDisplay`](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/52d45496877b00852a08a5b9819d109c2fd9bfab/Rendering/Core/vtkViewport.cxx#L219) is incorrect. It should read:

```cpp
dx = (v[0] + 1.0) * (sizex*(vp[2]-vp[0])) / 2.0 + sizex*vp[0];
dy = (v[1] + 1.0) * (sizey*(vp[3]-vp[1])) / 2.0 + sizey*vp[1];
```

Note, that `v` refers to the normalised view coordinates, `vp` is the viewport (by default, `vp := [0, 0, 1, 1]`)!

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is indeed valid, although there might be built-in ways to obtain the final matrix.

Assuming only one (default) viewport is used, the matrix converting the view into display coordinates is:

```
M = [X/2,   0, 0, X/2,
       0, Y/2, 0, Y/2,
       0,   0, 1,   0,
       0,   0, 0,   1]
```

where `X` and `Y` is the width and height of the image in pixels.
Hence, given a point `x` in the world coordinates, the display coordinates in homogeneous form are:

```
c = M * P * x;
```

where `P` is the `CompositeProjectionTransformMatrix`. After normalising (`c[i] /= c[3]`, `i = 0,1,2`) we arrive at the original pixel values.